# XmlHttpRequest в Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest

Всем добрый день! Пришло время разобраться с такой чудесной штукой как javascript и 5ый день все никак не могу разобраться как его применить на моем приложении Spring MVC, прошу помощи, кто сможет по пунктам объяснить как, например, со страницы со списком книг отправить POST запрос в контроллер, который передает название книги, которую надо добавить и без перезагрузки страницы книга появляется в списке ? Так же буду очень благодарен на полезные ссылки по этой теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не использовал еще XmlHttpRequest, всегда использую Ajax в таких целях:

1. Подключаем jquery, как обычный javascript

   ```
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"
   ```
2. На странице, добавляем javascript файл, где будет код ajax.
3. Пишем сам код:

   ```
   function sendData() {
   $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url : window.location.pathname,
       data : JSON.stringify({
           // Формат данных в JSON
           title : $("#titleId").val(),
           text : $("#textId").val()
       }),
       complete: function () {
           // По завершению
           $("#titleId").val("");
           $("#textId").val("");
       }
   });}
   ```
4. Контроллер:

   @RequestMapping(value = "url", method = POST)
   public void send(@RequestBody String json) {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("title") + " // " +  jsonObject.getString("text"));
   }

Comment: Спасибо! Буду от этого отталкиваться